# Surface integral on $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x+y+z\leq 1\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

Let $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x+y+z\leq 1\}$, $F(x,y,z)=(x,0,-x)$ and $n(x,y,z)$ be the unit normal vector of $S$ such that $n(0,0,-1)=(0,0,-1)$.
I want to evaluate $\displaystyle \iint_{S}F(x,y,z)\cdot n(x,y,z)dS$.

**My Attempt**

Let $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. Then $n$ can be calculated by $n=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}=(x,y,z)$. This satisfies the condition stated in the problem.

Therefore we have $\displaystyle \iint_{S}F(x,y,z)\cdot n(x,y,z)dS=\iint_{S}(x^2-zx)dS$. Now we need to calculate this surface integral, but I'm encountering issues.

According to [this website](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegralsintro.aspx), I have two options. One option is to find an orthogonal projection of $S$. The other option is to find a parameterization of $S$. However, I couldn't do either of them. Is there a simple expression for them? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Divergence Theorem?

Comment: @MathLover Yes. Is it possible to do something with it? I feel like it doesn't really go well.

Comment: I feel it is easier to just apply divergence theorem here (esp. given how the vector field is set up) than to individually find flux through the spherical surface (part of it) and the planar part. Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will present three ways of tackling this problem.

$\textbf{Option 1}$: Directly

Parametrizing spherical coordinates as usual we can find the bounds by examining the plane equation

$$x+y+z = 1 \implies \sin\phi\cos\theta+\sin\phi\sin\theta+\cos\phi = 1$$

which after a little manipulation becomes

$$\cos\theta+\sin\theta = \frac{1-\cos\phi}{\sin\phi} = \tan\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)$$

It's obvious from looking at the sphere with the planar cap cutoff that doing the $\theta$ integral first would require two integrals (one each for the upper and lower parts), but $\phi$ first would only require one. Writing the integral gets us

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{2\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}\right)}^\pi \sin^3\phi\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\phi\cos\phi\cos\theta\:d\phi d\theta$$

$\textbf{Option 2}$: Rotate then directly

Once we have the scalar surface integral $\iint_S x^2-xz\:dS$ we can consider a change of variables to rotate the plane so it is completely horizontal from the top. The closest distance between the plane and the origin is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so hopefully that motivates the following rotational coordinate change:

$$\begin{cases}u = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}} \\ v = \frac{x+y-2z}{\sqrt{6}} \\ w = \frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt{3}}\\ \end{cases}$$

This change of variables is a pure rotation so it has Jacobian $1$. This was obtained by choosing a direction for the new '$z$' and '$x$' ($w$ and $u$, respectively) then taking their cross product to find the third orthogonal vector (then including the factor to make them unit vectors), which means

$$u^2+v^2+w^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$$

Since this is a rotation matrix, inverting the system of equations is as easy as taking the transpose:

$$\begin{cases}x = \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{v}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{w}{\sqrt{3}} \\ y = -\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{v}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{w}{\sqrt{3}} \\ z =  -\frac{2v}{\sqrt{6}} + \frac{w}{\sqrt{3}} \\ \end{cases}$$

which gives us a new surface integral on the same sphere, only rotated

$$\iint_S \frac{u^2+v^2}{2}+\frac{2uv}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{uw}{\sqrt{6}}+\frac{vw}{\sqrt{2}}\:dS$$

The nice thing about this is that with this rotated sphere cutoff at $w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, we can now exploit symmetry. $u$ and $v$ are both odd functions, so any term with just an odd power of either will vanish, leaving us with

$$\iint_S \frac{u^2+v^2}{2}\:dS = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}^\pi \frac{1}{2}\sin^3\phi\:d\phi d\theta$$

which easy enough to evaluate since the integrand will end up being only cosines.

$\textbf{Option 3}:$ Divergence theorem

We close off the surface with a plane and consider the equation

$$\iint_{\text{sphere}}F\cdot dS + \iint_{\text{plane}}F\cdot dS = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot F dV$$ $$ = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^1 \int_{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\rho}\right)}^\pi\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\phi d\rho d\theta + \frac{4}{3}\pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^3$$

Since $\nabla\cdot F = 1$, we only want the volume, thus we have implicitly taken advantage of the rotation from option 2 to set up our bounds. The remaining surface integral can be calculated as follows

$$\iint_{\text{plane}}F\cdot dS = \iint_{\text{plane}}(x,0,-x)\cdot\frac{(1,1,1)}{\sqrt{3}}dS = 0$$

therefore the answer will only be the volume integral.

Comment: @MathLover you sent the comment right after I fixed it! But that was the only mistake in the bounds. The first integral only gives angles in the wrong quadrant for negative numbers, we can fix this by using arccot instead.

Comment: OK my internet is slow where I am. I see the last one now fixed but I am still not sure the first one is correct. When you rotate and use change of variable, it would work correctly. But when you do as-is, the lower limit of $\phi$ is a function of $\rho$ and I do not see how the setup takes care of that.

Comment: @MathLover I'm not sure I see the $\rho$ in the first integral, can you explain further?

Comment: Thanks for responding. My point is that you are trying to express the integral as a function of $\phi, \theta$ without $\rho$ but the way it is currently expressed $\phi \,$ goes from $f(\theta)$ to $\pi$. But the plane cuts the sphere somewhere between $0$ and $\pi$ (say $\phi_1 \leq \phi \leq \phi_2$). So I think the integral has to split into two. It may not give correct result as is.

Answer (score 2):

The question should have been more explicit but here is how I read the question -

Sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ is cut by the plane $x + y + z = 1$ and you are taking the part which is bigger (below the plane $x + y + z = 1$). Please note this surface has a spherical part and a planar part (circle) and applying divergence theorem will give the flux through the entire surface including the planar part.

Vector Field $\vec{F} = (x, 0, -x)$

$div \vec{F} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x) + 0 + \frac{\partial }{\partial z} (-x) = 1$

$\iint_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} \, dS = \iiint_S div{\vec{F}} \,dV = \iiint_S \,dV = V$

So all we are left with is to find the volume $V$ of our surface.

The unit normal vector to the plane $x + y + z = 1$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(1, 1, 1)$ which is also a point on the sphere. The line from the origin that is perp to the plane is $\frac{t}{\sqrt3}(1, 1, 1)$ and the foot of the perp on the plane is $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}) \,$ for $t = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$. The length of the perp is $\frac{1}{\sqrt3} \,$ which comes from $\, (\sqrt{(\frac{1}{3})^2 + (\frac{1}{3})^2 + (\frac{1}{3})^2} \,).$

So the smaller part of the sphere cut by the plane is a spherical cap of height $(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt3})$.

You can either use the formula for spherical cap volume, if you remember, or considering symmetry, the volume of the spherical cap can be easily calculated as -

$V_1 = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt3})} \int_{\frac{1} {\sqrt3 \cos \phi}}^1 \rho^2 \sin \phi \, d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta \approx 0.482129$

Volume you are interested in $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi - V_1 \approx 3.707$

EDIT: if the planar part is not part of the surface then we can subtract flux through the planar surface but please note that -

$\vec{F} \cdot n = (x, 0, -x) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt3}(1, 1, 1) = 0$ so the flux through the planar part is zero.

Comment: I suppose the divergence theorem also considers flux through the circle-part ($x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1, x + y + z = 1$ which does not belong to $S$), so you also need to subtract it from the volume.

Comment: That is not correct. It is a closed surface and the surface includes both the spherical part and the circular part. So when you are finding flux using the surface integral, you will have to find for both and add. That is how I read the question.

Comment: Please note $x + y + z \leq 1$ is part of the surface. That equality considers all points on the plane $x + y + z = 1$ that is part of the sphere.

Comment: Whoops, please forget about the deleted comment. The thing I wanted to say is the same as @IPPK. I think $S$ only represents the spherical part, so I think we need to subtract the planar part from the volume.

Comment: $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x+y+z\leq 1\}$ and it includes the part $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1, x + y + z = 1$ but not the $x^2+y^2+z^2 < 1, x + y + z = 1$ part.

Comment: @Kaira I read it as the planar part is part of the surface. If it is not, then we can subtract it. But that is anyway zero.

Comment: @MathLover Oh yeah, I missed that. Thanks.